# Regex to grab Date from String

Tags: php, regex, parsing, date

I'm trying to grab part of a string that represents a date.

The date-string will usually, but not always, have regular text before and/or after it.

In this example:

```
Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here
```

I would want the result to be:

```
Sun, Apr 09, 2000
```

Bear in mind that days and month strings can be 3 or 4 characters in length.

My meager attempt is:

```
$test = "Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here";

if (ereg ("/([a-z]{3,4}),.([a-z]{3,4}).([0-9]{1,2}),.([0-9]{4})/i", $test, $regs)) {
    echo "$regs[4].$regs[3].$regs[2].$regs[1]";
}
```

Also interested in hearing non-regex based solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to work in multiple cases:

```
$str = "Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here";
$reg = '/(\w{3}),\s*(\w{3})\s*(\d+),\s*(\d{4})/';

$match = preg_match($reg, $str, $matches);

if ($match) {
    $date = "{$matches[2]} {$matches[3]} {$matches[4]}\n";
    // Apr 09 2000
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
}
```

[ereg()](http://php.net/ereg) should no longer be used, as of PHP 5.3.0 it is deprecated and preg has long been favored as a faster, more widely used alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Someone could probably do better than this as it's pretty verbose:

```
/(?:mon|tues?|weds|thurs?|fri|sat|sun), [a-z]{3,4} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}/i

$regex = '/(?:mon|tues?|weds|thurs?|fri|sat|sun), [a-z]{3,4} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}/i';
$string = 'Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here';

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
// Sun, Apr 09, 2000
```

If you're expecting the date to occur multiple times, a minor change helps.

```
// store the match as a named parameter called 'date'
$regex = '/(?<date>(?:sun|mon|tues?|weds|thurs?|fri|sat|sun), [a-z]{3,4} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4})/i';

$string = 'Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here. Sun, Mar 10, 2010';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches['date']);
/* 
 Array
    (
        [0] => Sun, Apr 09, 2000
        [1] => Sun, Mar 10, 2010
    )
*/
```

Started off with the name of the day, just on the off chance you get something that looks the same as a day but isn't.

I'd also not suggest using `ereg()` as it was deprecated in 5.3.0. Use `preg_match()` instead, or one of the other `preg_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on deprecated `ereg`, try [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$str = "Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here";

preg_match_all('/.*([A-Za-z]{3,4}, [A-Za-z]{3,4} [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4}).*/',$str,$matches);
```

**Output**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sometimes text is here, Sun, Apr 09, 2000  And sometimes but not always text here
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sun, Apr 09, 2000
        )

)
```

You'll find all matches in `$matches[1]`.